# Stm32 printf float variable

Tags: printf, stm32

I want to log out from stm32f405 via usart. 
In my syscall.c file i realize function to print via usart:

```
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
    int todo;
    for (todo = 0; todo < len; todo++)
    {
    usart_send_char( *ptr++ );
    }
    return len;
}
```

Function `usart_send_char( *ptr++ );` work as expected. But when i call:

```
printf("%s, %d, %3.2f\r\n", "asd", 777, 13.2 );
```

I get:
 `asd, 777, 0.00`
The float variable not printed correctly.

Makefile:

```
PROCESSOR = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
CFLAGS += $(PROCESSOR) $(INCLUDES) $(STFLAGS) -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing $(C_PROFILE)
LDFLAGS = $(PROCESSOR) -Wl,-Map=$(PROG).map,--cref,--gc-sections
```

Used compilator:

```
Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2014.05-28
```

Where i am mistaken?

Comment: You've got two correct answers. Please, vote for one of them and mark this question solved.

Answer (score 25):

I haven't used Sourcery Codebench gcc for STM32F4, but with the [GCC ARM Embedded toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded), floating point support in printf isn't enabled by default. To enable, add `-u _printf_float` to your LDFLAGS.

Answer (score 7):

1. I am not sure, but I think the mfloat-abi-flag must be set for the
   CFLAGS.
2. STM32F4 has a FPU, so why do you use mfloat-abi=soft? Can't you use mfloat-abi=hard?
3. If you don't need to calculate floatingpointvalue very often, you could do it in this way.

Code example:

```
 int i = 132;
 printf("Result is: %d.%d", i/10, i%10);
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: Snapshot of where you addd the command -u _printf_float in STM project settings]

To enable the floats in sprintf, add -u _printf_float to your project as this picture indicate.

Comment: Thank you, done, but warning not disappear

Answer (score 1):

The STM32cubeIDE has a checkbox for this capability but, apparently, it does the same thing as has been suggested: -u _printf_float. AND there's a separate one for _scanf_float. Right click on the project name and select "Properties" (at the bottom of the list).

[image: Properties dialog box]