# Crossworks String Conversion

Tags: c++, stm32, freertos

We are using Crossworks IDE to run freeRTOS in C++. Here, we are sending data via serial com using "HAL_UART_Transmit" built in STM32_HAL function. We want to send Sensor data via serial com to external device.

here is an exmaple format:

```
float humiditySensorValues[2];
uint8_t buffer[100] =  {"Temperature = ? \r\n"} ;    

HAL_UART_Transmit(&husart3, buffer, sizeof(buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

In the above code we want to replace **"? -> humiditySensorValues[0]"** and send the data.

where **humiditySensorValues[0]** contains updated temperature data value in degrees.

Any suggestion to resolve the above issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `snprintf(buffer, 100, "Temperature = %f \r\n", humiditySensorValues[0]);`  You mention C++, but the question is tagged C, and `snprintf` is arguably not appropriate in C++.

Comment: I suggest to learn C first, then to start uC programming. Eithout basic knowledge it is not possible write programs.

Comment: If you are using C++ then tag your question C++ not C. String handling is quite different between the two languages. C++ opens up the option to make something even less efficient than sprintf (which is an achievement!) by using sstream or std::string with heap allocation and all manner of other PC goo.

Comment: You might also want to mention with STM32 this is, because using floating point on Cortex M below M4 without FPU is quackery - it will link in horrible software floating point libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `snprintf`:

```
char buffer[100] = {0};
int len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Temperature = %f \r\n", (double)humiditySensorValues[0]);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&husart3, (uint8_t*)buffer, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Do not use `sprintf` as that does not check for buffer overflow.

Comment: also, add how to print floats as ARM standard library has float printf support disabled.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland, it can be enabled, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334435/stm32-printf-float-variable) post.