# Some questions about using float, snprintf, sprtinf on STM32

Tags: floating-point, stm32

I would like to advise you, I create software for the STM32L151C8 microcontroller that will control the LCD segment display via the I2C PCF85176 driver

Design:

- battery powered
- configurable by the attached bluetooth module and keeping configuration values ​​in EEPROM / FLASH
- pulse ounter on the interrupt and holding the value in the flash, the device does not reset after inserting the battery
- displaying on LCD pulse values ​​after simple mathematical operations (addition, multiplication)

My questions:

using the snprintf / sprintf function to convert floats to char array - it uses a lot of memory?
using float (this MCU don't have FPU i should using uint and only add dot on LCD?)
I choose good MCU for this application?

```
void LCD_Update(void) {
    uint8_t msg[2+20];
    uint8_t *display_mem=msg+2;
    msg[0]=CMD_OPCODE_DEVICE_SELECT | 0 | CMD_CONTINUE;
    msg[1]=CMD_OPCODE_LOAD_DATA_POINTER | 0;
    memset(display_mem, 0, 20);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            uint8_t nibble=(display_digits[i]>>(4*j))&0xf;
            uint8_t nibbleaddr=digit_addrs[i][j];
            uint8_t byteaddr=nibbleaddr>>1;
            nibbleaddr&=1;
            display_mem[byteaddr]|=nibble<<(4*nibbleaddr);
        }
    }
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, PCF8576_ADDR, msg, sizeof(msg), 100);
}
 
void LCD_Clear(void) {
    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++) {
        display_digits[i]=0;
    }
    LCD_Update();
}
 
void LCD_Print(char* str) {
    int idx=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++) {
        char c=str[i];
        if(c>='A' && c<='Z') {
            display_digits[idx]=alpha[c-'A'];
        }
        else if (c=='.') {
            display_digits[idx-1]=numsDot[str[i-1]-'0'];
            idx--;
        }
        else if(c>='0' && c<='9') {
            display_digits[idx]=nums[c-'0'];
        }
        idx++;
    }
    LCD_Update();
}
 
void LCD_PrintInt(int value) {
    char str[8];
    sprintf(str, "%d", value);
    LCD_Print(str);
}
 
void LCD_PrintFloat(float value, uint8_t length) {
    char str[length];
    snprintf(str, length + 1, "%f", value);
    LCD_Print(str);
}
```

Above is fragment of my program to control LCD

Comment: You just have to look to the map file, ie. the file giving the size and location of every section of your executable.

Comment: @user22090909 are you asking about RAM or flash/ROM?

Answer (score 0):

To address you two questions:

1/ Float point calcuations are achieved by software if the MCU has no FPU. And yes, there will be more code so more memory used. But I believe that would be enough for your application. You can use you current MCU.

2/ You can print directly float using sprintf family functions and print on your LCD. By default this is disabled on STM32 compiler. you need to add the
`-u _printf_float` flag to you linker to enable this feature.
You can refer to this [forum](https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread954).  This was also answered in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334435/stm32-printf-float-variable)